# How to install node.js in windows?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js.

can someone tell me the steps to install node.js in my machine.

I'm using windows 7 and visual studio 2012 as development environment.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we can't do much besides pointing you to the docs http://nodejs.org/download/

Answer (score 3):

Download the node.js installer (.msi) file from the follwoing link:

http://nodejs.org/

and then run the installer by double clicking and following instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows installer; It available here - http://nodejs.org/download/